# How can I insert json data from json file into rect and create table?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have a local file called "contacts.json" . I want to insert it in react component and create a table . I'll be so glad if anybody can help me .Thanks .

```
{
  "contacts": [
  {
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "hamid",
  "lastName": "mohamadi",
  "contactType": "Friend",
  "birthDate": "2010.10.10",
  "phoneNumber": [
    "09011019011",
    "09120658719"
  ],
  "email": [
    "mohammadi842@gmail.com",
    "h_mohammadi842@yahoo.com"
  ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can you use `JSON.parse()`:

```
const obj = JSON.parse();
render(<MyComponent data={obj} />)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its already are a valid js object. I did an example of an html table with this data:

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-heyrovsky-w8d51

you can choose to iterate like a did or specify which attribute you would like to show.

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
      {data.contacts.map(contact => {
        return Object.keys(contact).map((item, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{contact[item]}</td>
          </tr>
        ));
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do is `const obj = JSON.parse(value)`
`console.log('obj'+obj)`

after you need to do is in **return**( `{this.props.obj.map((number) => <p key={number}>{number}</p>                    )}`)